# what does the # symbol mean in an f# function signature?

Tags: types, casting, f#, symbols, type-signature

I have seen a function defined like this:

```
let private applyTarget (logger:#ILogger) ceiling target =
    logger.Debug "enforce ceiling"
    match target > ceiling with
    | true -> ceiling | false -> target
```

What does the *#* symbol mean in the signature?

Whats the difference between `logger:ILogger` and `logger:#ILogger`?

Comment: I believe it is a [flexible type annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/flexible-types-%5bfsharp%5d). I suspect since upcasting in F# is not always implicit it makes sense to not force it on callers by using a flexible type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A type signature `#t` is called *"flexible type"*, and is just shorthand for `'a when 'a :> t`.

That is, `#t` means *"any subtype of `t`"*.